# How to add WooCommerce variation automatically when press on button?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

I have product category called "the-collection" with many products inside. All of that products is variable products with variations inside. I have variation with Size: "Simple Pot" and Finish: "Chalky Interior Matt"  inside. I want to add custom button, that will auto add this varialtion into cart. For that i added this function into functions.php file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button()
{
  echo '<a href="#" button type="submit" class="button alt">Sample 
Pot</button></a>';

}
```

That add me a button. I also followed this [manual](https://nicola.blog/2015/09/18/creating-custom-add-to-cart-url/) how to create varaible link, but variation ID is not exact for all products. I also want to show that button only for "The Collection" product category. How to do that?

Comment: woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button will not give you product ID... but in product page if you take gobal var $post inside your call back function it will give you the product, with that product ID you can get it's variations and populate the links as per your need.

Comment: You should be able to `global $product` to get the variable product object on that hook.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button()
{
  echo '<a href="cart/?add-to-cart=10233&variation_id=10234&attribute_pa_color=red" button type="submit" class="button alt">Sample 
Pot</a>';

}
```

try the snippet like this

Comment: variation_id=10234 is not the same for every product. so this cant use fr all products that have that variations in category.